# Error: unable to open display :99 on FFMpeg

Tags: linux, java, ffmpeg

I installed FFmpeg on a Linux Ubuntu machine using "snap".

When I run FFmpeg on the remote machine using SSH it seems to work fine.

When I run FFMpeg from Java on the machine (Unit tests when running Jenkins) I get the following error:

```
Error: unable to open display :99
ffmpeg version n4.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix= --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-static --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-libdrm --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-sdl2 --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-xlib
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
/tmp/video_temp_file_1481104454486758468.mp4: No such file or directory
```

Any idea? am I missing anything?

Comment: Snap applications have limited permissions and this *may* be the cause. What happens if you install ffmpeg from the repos with apt? That's where I'd first start troubleshooting with this one.

Comment: Thanks, apt was my first attempt to install ffmpeg. For some reason it didn't run apt update due to some AWS IAM issue, so I installed snap with apt and then ffmpeg with snap, but now getting this error. I guess there is no way around it & I will have to try to install it with apt.. THANKS